# merging two dataframes in such a way that the indexes are preserved

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b'], 'col2': ['p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'q', 't']})
df1
[Output]:
    col1    col2
0   a        p
1   b        q
2   c        r
3   d        s
4   e        t
5   a        q
6   b        t

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'b'], 'col2': ['p', 'q', 'r', 't', 't'], 'col3': ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']})
df2
[Output]:

   col1 col2 col3
0   a    p   val0
1   b    q   val1
2   c    r   val2
3   e    t   val3
4   b    t   val4
```

`col1` and `col2` in both dataframes are the same. The only difference between the two dataframes is that the df2 has some missing rows as compared to df1.

I need another dataframe, `df3` that would be equivalent to merged `df1` and `df2`, would have all the rows from `df1`, would have another column `col3` and would also preserve the indexes from `df1`.
For example:

```
df3
[Output]:
    col1  col2  col3
0    a     p    val0
1    b     q    val1
2    c     r    val2
3    d     s    Nan
4    e     t    val3
5    a     q    Nan
6    b     t    val4
```

I am unable to make this work using `merge`, `join` or `concat`. I am sure it's something very simple but I just can not bring my head around the logic.

Please note that the col3 values depend on the combination of col1 and col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `df1` as base and left merge (with `how='left'`) with `df2` with merging on both the columns `col1` and `col2`, as follows:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['col1', 'col2'], how='left')
```

With `how='left'`, Pandas uses only keys from left frame, similar to a SQL left outer join; preserve key order.  Hence the row index of `df1` will be preserved.

Result:

```
print(df3)


  col1 col2  col3
0    a    p  val0
1    b    q  val1
2    c    r  val2
3    d    s   NaN
4    e    t  val3
5    a    q   NaN
6    b    t  val4
```